# Laravel 4 - Input::old for radio buttons

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if some Laravel guys can help out.

I have a form in which i have 2 radio buttons, when the form submits it goes through the validator, if the validator fails it comes back to the form, populates the fields with the input and displays error messages.

I cant seem to do this for radio buttons, if one is clicked when the form is submitted and there was an error, it comes back to the form with everything filled out EXCEPT the radio button that was checked is now empty.

My radio buttons are as follows:

```
<input type="radio" name="genre" value="M" class="radio" id="male" />
<input type="radio" name="genre" value="F" class="radio" id="female" />
<span class="error">{{ $errors->first('genre') }}</span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<input type="radio" name="genre" value="M" class="radio" id="male" <?php if(Input::old('genre')== "M") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> >
<input type="radio" name="genre" value="F" class="radio" id="female" <?php if(Input::old('genre')== "F") { echo 'checked="checked"; } ?> >
```

Comment: Hey, that would check the male radio button by default though wouldnt it?

Comment: Yeah it would, you could switch it around so that female was default. But if you wanted you could put an if statement in both input fields.

Comment: Do you not want any radio input to be selected by default? I updated my code so no input is checked by default.

Answer (score 19):

You can try this using Laravel's out of the box HTML radio...
[Laravel Docs Form checkboxes and Radio](http://laravel.com/docs/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons)

Using blade,

```
{{ Form::radio('genre', 'M', (Input::old('genre') == 'M'), array('id'=>'male', 'class'=>'radio')) }}
{{ Form::radio('genre', 'F', (Input::old('genre') == 'F'), array('id'=>'female', 'class'=>'radio')) }}
```

Or just php,

```
echo Form::radio('genre', 'M', (Input::old('genre') == 'M'), array('id'=>'male', 'class'=>'radio'));
echo Form::radio('genre', 'F', (Input::old('genre') == 'F'), array('id'=>'female', 'class'=>'radio'));
```

Comment: Im seeing this 'Method radio does not exist.' when i use this

Comment: It doesn't appear that the code in question is using blade templating or the laravel HTML / Form helpers

Comment: Oops... Just suggesting.. since he mentioned laravel.. Cheers

Comment: @BigJobbies just edited it.. use Form::radio() instead of HTML::radio().. my bad..

Comment: +1 No need for a ternary here though, just pass in `Input::old('genre') == 'M'` as the value of the parameter.

Comment: How can I use this with `Form::model`? I have a model `User` and a model `Seller`and I need to get some seller data and use it on a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is known :
- https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2069
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1564

You have a temporary solution in the second link.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question being asked.

Comment: You're right this doesn't really answer but I hope it will be fixed soon :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled into this and I don't want to keep repeating such conditions on every form, so I've created a function on my Helper class.

Helper.php:

```
class Helper {

    // other functions

    public static function oldRadio($name, $value, $default = false) {
        if(empty($name) || empty($value) || !is_bool($default))
            return '';

        if(null !== Input::old($name)) {
            if(Input::old($name) == $value) {
                return 'checked';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        } else {
            if($default) {
                return 'checked';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        // Or, short version:
        return null !== Input::old($name) ? (Input::old($name) == $value ? 'checked' : '') : ($default ? 'checked' : '');
    }
}
```

So, now on my forms, I just use it like this:

```html
<label>Please select whatever you want</label>
<div class="radio-inline"><label><input type="radio" name="whatever" value="1" required {{ Helper::oldRadio('whatever', '1', true) }}> One</label></div>
<div class="radio-inline"><label><input type="radio" name="whatever" value="2" {{ Helper::oldRadio('whatever', '2') }}> Two</label></div>
<div class="radio-inline"><label><input type="radio" name="whatever" value="3" {{ Helper::oldRadio('whatever', '3') }}> Three</label></div>
```

Each option passes its name and value to the helper function and the previously selected one will print 'checked'. Additionally, an option can pass 'true' as the third parameter so it gets selected if there was no old input.

Answer (score 1):

**Using with the Bootstrap & Automatic checking**

*Add this code at end of file:* app/start/global.php

```
//...

Form::macro('radio2', function($group ='group-name', $value_model = 'value-model', $label ='label-radio', $value_radio = 'value-radio', $attrs = array())
{

  $item  = "<div class='radio'>";
  $item .=   "<label>";
  $item .=      Form::radio($group, $value_radio, ($value_model == $value_radio) ? true : false, $attrs);
  $item .=      $label;
  $item .=   "</label>";
  $item .= "</div>";

  return $item;
});
```

In your view.php

```php
{{ Form::radio2('status', Input::old('status'), 'Online', '1', array()) }}
{{ Form::radio2('status', Input::old('status'), 'Offline', '0', array()) }}
```

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried simply using Input::get() instead of Input::old().... and it's worked!!`{{Form::radio('estado','V',(Input::get('estado')=="V"))}}`

Answer (score 0):

My approach is a nested shorthand if/else statement with blade syntax. This solution considers also the initial value that is set in the database.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"{!! ((old('sex') == 'male') ? ' checked="checked"' : ((empty(old('sex')) && $user->sex == 'male') ? ' checked="checked"' : '')) !!}/>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="male">Männlich</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"{!! ((old('sex') == 'female') ? ' checked="checked"' : ((empty(old('sex')) && $user->sex == 'female') ? ' checked="checked"' : '')) !!}/>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="female">Weiblich</label>
</div>
```

Tested with Laravel 5.7.