# Radio button not retrieving old values from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, radio-button, return-value

Hi Iam using laravel framework for my application i have radio buttons namely wdv & slm the corresponding values are getting saved in database but i am  not able to retrive the saved value while editing the form i tried different solutions but i couldn't crack it,i do know what am i doing wrong please guide me to solve this issue..

**My edit.blade.php**

```
<!-- Depreciation Type -->
            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('depreciation_type') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="depreciation_type" class="col-md-3 control-label depreciationlabel">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.depreciation')</label>
                    <div class="controls col-md-7">
                        {{ Form::radio('depreciation_type', 'wdv', Input::old('depreciation_type', $assetdetail->depreciation_type), array('id'=>'wdv', 'class'=>'wdvbutton')) }}
                        <label for="wdv" class="col-md-3 control-label wdvlabel">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.wdv')</label>
                        {{ Form::radio('depreciation_type', 'slm', Input::old('depreciation_type', $assetdetail->depreciation_type), array('id'=>'slm','class'=>'wdvbutton')) }}
                        <label for="slm" class="col-md-3 control-label slmlabel">@lang('admin/assetdetails/form.slm')</label></br>
                        {{ $errors->first('depreciation_type', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="icon-remove-sign"></i> :message</span>') }}
                    </div>
            </div>
```

**Controller file**

```
public function getEdit($assetdetailId = null)
    {
        // Check if the location exists
        if (is_null($assetdetail = Assetdetail::find($assetdetailId)))
        {
            // Redirect to the blogs management page
            return Redirect::to('admin/settings/assetdetails')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/message.does_not_exist'));
        }
        $location_list = array('' => '') + Location::lists('name', 'id');
        $assettype_list = array('' => '') + Assettype::lists('asset_type', 'id');

        // Show the page
        //$location_options = array('' => 'Top Level') + Location::lists('name', 'id');

        $assetdetail_options = array('' => 'Top Level') + DB::table('asset_details')->where('id', '!=', $assetdetailId)->lists('asset_number', 'id');
        return View::make('backend/assetdetails/edit', compact('assetdetail'))->with('assetdetail_options',$assetdetail_options)->with('location_list',$location_list)->with('assettype_list',$assettype_list);
    }


    /**
     * Location update form processing page.
     *
     * @param  int  $locationId
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function postEdit($assetdetailId = null)
    {
        // Check if the location exists
        if (is_null($assetdetail = Assetdetail::find($assetdetailId)))
        {
            // Redirect to the blogs management page
            return Redirect::to('admin/settings/assetdetails')->with('error', Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/message.does_not_exist'));
        }



        // get the POST data
        $new = Input::all();


        // attempt validation
        if ($assetdetail->validate($new))
        {

            // Update the location data

            $assetdetail ->asset_number             = e(Input::get('asset_number'));
            $assetdetail ->location_id              = e(Input::get('location_id'));
            $assetdetail ->assign_to                = e(Input::get('assign_to'));
            $assetdetail ->asset_type_id            = e(Input::get('asset_type_id'));
            $assetdetail ->nesd                     = e(Input::get('nesd'));
            $assetdetail ->active                   = e(Input::get('active'));
            $assetdetail ->shift                    = e(Input::get('shift'));
            $assetdetail ->supplier_name            = e(Input::get('supplier_name'));
            $assetdetail ->description              = e(Input::get('description'));
            $assetdetail ->dateof_purchase          = e(Input::get('dateof_purchase'));
            $assetdetail ->label_number             = e(Input::get('label_number'));
            $assetdetail ->purchase_price           = e(Input::get('purchase_price'));
            $assetdetail ->dateof_disposed          = e(Input::get('dateof_disposed'));
            $assetdetail ->depreciation_type        = e(Input::get('depreciation_type'));
            $assetdetail ->salvage_value            = e(Input::get('salvage_value'));
            $assetdetail ->asset_life               = e(Input::get('asset_life'));




            // Was the asset created?
            if($assetdetail->save())
            {
                // Redirect to the saved location page
                return Redirect::to("admin/settings/assetdetails/$assetdetailId/edit")->with('success', Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/message.update.success'));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // failure
            $errors = $assetdetail->errors();
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
        }

        // Redirect to the location management page
        return Redirect::to("admin/settings/assetdetails/$assetdetailId/edit")->with('error', Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/message.update.error'));

    }
```

Note:I am using varchar as my datatype to save my radio button values in database as wdv & slm

**I tried**

```
{{ Form::radio('depriciation_type', 'wdv', (Input::old('depriciation_type') == 'wdv'), array('id'=>'wdv', 'class'=>'radio')) }}
{{ Form::radio('depriciation_type', 'slm', (Input::old('depriciation_type') == 'slm'), array('id'=>'slm', 'class'=>'radio')) }}
```

**I also tried**

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="wdv" class="radio" id="wdv" <?php if(Input::old('type')== "wdv") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> >
<input type="radio" name="type" value="slm" class="radio" id="slm" <?php if(Input::old('type')== "slm") { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> >
```

Should i need to add anything in route file.

Please help me to solve this issue..Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - Input::old for radio buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059244/laravel-4-inputold-for-radio-buttons)

Comment: @Jerodev thanks for your reply i have already tried this you can see my post above, if anything is wrong in that please let me know.(see I also tried)

Comment: @Jerodev is there any thing else that i could do instead to get this work.

Comment: Can you put `dd(Input::All)` in your code and see what the value of `deprication_type` is?

Comment: @Jerodev i tried using Input::All instead of Input::old in view page but the value is not retrieved.I found that by using Input::Old defaultly slm gets checked while editing even if i save the depreciation_type value as wdv. I do know why this is happening.But the value gets saved as wdv in database.

Comment: @Jerodev do you know how to retrieve correct value for radio button from database while editing the form in laravel, because values are correctly getting saved in database only while editing it defaultly checks the slm value.

Comment: @menjaraz please help me to solve this issue

Comment: @Jerodev sorry i misunderstood what u said i tried dd(Input::All ('depriciation_type')); in controller it returned array(0) { }

Comment: you need to call the function without any parameter :)

Comment: @Jerodev can u please elaborate your answer i couldn't understand what you told.

Comment: You don't use any parameter when using `Input::All()`, you just do `dd(Input::All());` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself this is what i did

```
{{ Form::radio('depreciation_type', 'wdv', Input::old('depreciation_type', $assetdetail->depreciation_type == 'wdv' ), array('id'=>'wdv', 'class'=>'wdvbutton')) }}
{{ Form::radio('depreciation_type', 'slm', Input::old('depreciation_type', $assetdetail->depreciation_type == 'slm' ), array('id'=>'slm', 'class'=>'slmbutton')) }}
```